# Setting time for a session to timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that this question has been asked a lot on here but none of the solutions that people offered seemed to really work for me. I am trying to extend the length of time that sessions remain active on my website I tried modifying web.config with:

```
  <sessionState timeout="45"/>
```

And setting Session.Timeout in the code behind but nether of those worked as intended. I would like to get the sessions to last as long as possible, but as of right now they last about 10 minutes before i start to have issues.

Comment: The default timeout is 20 minutes, so if you are seeing problems after 10 minutes that seems indicative of another problem.

Comment: "before i start to have issues" is not exactly useful description of a problem. Normally session state uses sliding expiration, so suggestions will depend on type of "issues".

Comment: Do you happen to be Form authenticating users?

Comment: no form, I am using sessions to store data as I move from page to page. A more descriptive issue of the error I am having is after a short amount of time pages start to display errors that sessions they are trying to access are not set even though they were set earlier on in the process. I am using the default settings for the sessions so I am guessing that is sliding expiration.

Comment: you may also have problems with your idle timeout.  If the app goes to sleep you will lose your session data. By default your Idle timeout-minutes is set to 20 minutes on your app pool.  BUT as long as there is activity that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If your session state is setup to be InProc and you have multiple web servers or a web garden, then your session state could easily be lost.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net Session Management has two Modes.

**InProc**

Loss of Session is a common problem in this mode. IIS keep recycling the worker-process after some duration, which causes the loss of Session Data.

Have a look at below link for more informaton on this.

[Check this](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/07/21/in-proc-session-state-management.aspx)

**Below CodeProject article has a work-around for this problem.**

[Prevent Session Timeout in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Reconnect.aspx)

**OutProc**

In this mode of Session Management, settings of web.config will work properly. Have a look at below link for more details.

[check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**In WebConfig :**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionstate timeout="20" /> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

By default its 20 mins. Change it as per your needs.

**Check it in IIS**

1. Open the IIS, click on the Application Pool.
2. Select the Application
       pool for your application.
3. Right Click --> Select Properties.  In
       the Performance tab, Set the idle timeout as your
           desired minutes for "shutdown worker processes after being idle for
           ..... minutes".

Restart IIS after that.

[Why Session.Timeout is not working for your website](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Sessiontimeoutnotworking.aspx)